# C string comparison in an if statement doesn't work

Tags: c

I want to compare a previously typed string in an if statement, but it doesn't work. I have tried what explained in this thread: [Compare with string in if statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587574/compare-with-string-in-if-statement-doesnt-work)
but without luck.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char inputUnit[2];
float inputValue, returnValue;

int main() {

    printf("Enter value to convert: ");
    scanf("%f", &inputValue);

    printf("Enter unit to convert: ");
    scanf("%s", inputUnit);

    if (strcmp(inputUnit, "in")) {
        returnValue = inputValue * 2.54;
        printf("%.2f %s = %.4f cm\n", inputValue, inputUnit, returnValue);
    }
}
return (0);
```

So, what I did wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my strcmp() failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720533/why-is-my-strcmp-failing). I picked a pretty random answered one out of the current [271 false claims](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bc%5D+strcmp+wrong) that it is "wrong" – I didn't bother to check how many more there are that state "it doesn't work"

Comment: You need a length 3 character buffer to store two characters of string plus the NULL terminator. This code has undefined behaviour because you're exceeding the buffer length.

Comment: The global variables should not be global; they should all be local to `main()`.  Use global variables only when necessary; by default, variables should be local to a function.

Comment: @tadman:`NULL` and `NUL` are not the same. `NULL`  is the null-pointer literal. `NUL` is the character `'\0'`. You want the latter.

Comment: @alk Technically yes, but this distinction is rarely made. They're called [Null Terminated Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) which just so happens to use the `NUL` character code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 when both strings are equal.

It should be

```
if (strcmp(inputUnit, "in") == 0) {
    returnValue = inputValue * 2.54;
    printf("%.2f %s = %.4f cm\n", inputValue, inputUnit, returnValue);
}
```

See

> *man strcmp*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The  `strcmp()`  function  compares  the two strings `s1` and `s2`.
>   **It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than `s2`**.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` returns `0` if the strings compare equivalently.

Try negating your if statement, or checking for `0` explicitly.

```
if (!strcmp(...))
if (strcmp(...) == 0)
```

[**strcmp** Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

> **Return value**
>
> - Negative value if lhs appears before rhs in lexicographical order.
> - Zero if lhs and rhs compare equal.
> - Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcmp` function returns 0 if he strings match.  So you need to check if the function returns 0.

```
if (strcmp(inputUnit, "in") == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

strcmp returns 0 if the strings are the same. "man strcmp"

Answer (score 0):

the string compare function strcmp returns zero if the both strings are equal otherwise it return non-zero number .So use can use here in if statement not equal like  **!strcmp(inputUnit, "in")** .The strcmp function returns 0 and to true the if condition I am using not equal sign '!' so the !0=1 then if clause becomes true & it execute the if body.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char inputUnit[2];
float inputValue, returnValue;

int main() {

    printf("Enter value to convert: ");
    scanf("%f", &inputValue);

    printf("Enter unit to convert: ");
    scanf("%s", inputUnit);

    if (!strcmp(inputUnit, "in")) {
        returnValue = inputValue * 2.54;
        printf("%.2f %s = %.4f cm\n", inputValue, inputUnit, returnValue);
    }
    return (0);
}
```